# Ограничение подсказок ymaps SuggestView по нескольким регионам

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Реализовал ограничение для одного региона ymaps SuggestView в поле ввода таким образом. Все работает как надо.

```
   function init_sugg() {
    var locality = 'Краснодарский край';
    var suggestView1 = new ymaps.SuggestView('order_from', {
        provider: {
            suggest: (function (request, options) {
                return ymaps.suggest(locality + ", " + request)
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Подскажите как ограничить выдачу для нескольких регионов сразу? Чтоб в подсказках при вводе адреса выводилось населенные пункты только из данных регионов.
Пытался реализовать такой конструкцией:

```
var locality1 = 'Краснодарский край';
var locality2 = 'Ростовская область';
......

suggest: (function (request, options) {
                    return ymaps.suggest(locality1 + "," + locality2 + "," + request)
                })
```

Результат мне это не принесло.

Comment: Как вы запланировали, Яндекс не предлагает. Но что вам мешает сделать отдельное поле выбора locality с подготовленным вами списком территорий над саджестом, а не пытаться делать за пользователя каждое телодвижение? После этого выбранный регион будет подтягиваться к запросу саджеста.

Comment: Немного не понял что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Если вы предлагаете использовать список определенных городов, это не подойдёт. Необходимо реализовать расчет по маршруту и я не знаю какие адреса будут вводить пользователи, а списком прописать все не представляет возможности. Нужно чтобы пользователь начал вводить адрес и Яндекс предлагал.

Comment: Предлагал что? Вы сами пишете, что не знаете, что будет за город. Значит пользователю просто надо писать адрес с городом - стандартные подсказки помогут, когда будет понятно, что за адрес вводится.